# How to reset or start from scratch aws cdk configrations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have recently start using aws cdk as a newbie. so i ran lot of commands that i had no idea about.

now i want to remove all settings like env variables i created or profiles and start from scratch. what should in un install to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to reset but here's a few suggestions that might help:

**Remove Deployed CDK Stacks**

```
cdk destroy stack_name
```

Note: You'll have to do this for every stack you've deployed. This can also be done through "CloudFormation" in the AWS dashboard in your browser.

**Remove CLI Settings**

As per https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

> To remove a setting, use an empty string as the value, or manually delete the setting in your config and credentials files in a text editor.

Example:

```
aws configure set cli_pager ""
```

**Remove Profiles**

Unsure if you can do this easily through the CLI but you can just manually remove them from your config files. There are only two config files and they can be found using https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

> ~/.aws/credentials (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials (Windows)

> ~/.aws/config (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\config (Windows)

If you need more specific help on how to undo something then please provide an example of what exactly you ran that you would like to undo.

Comment: thanks for reply Alex this is the error im getting

Comment: thanks for reply Alex this is the error im getting
Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment
I tried :
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxTMYKEYID
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxEACCESSKEY
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
and also did aws configure after deleting profiles in config file but noting worked.

Comment: yea i deleted these two files and then ran aws configure but it did not work

Comment: Have you tried removing the environment variables? You can use `unset  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` etc to remove them all.

Comment: no i didnt do that 
but i solve the problem by uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling everything. and making new use in aws